# NodaTime timezone abbreviation from Instant

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

Got an excel export feature where the datetime column should be localized based on the browser location (14-Nov-2022 12:51 PM EST). Using NodaTime, I am able to localize it. However, I am not able to get the timezone abbreviation (PST, EST, CST etc..,) which needs to be appended at the end of the datetime string.

```
public static string ToSpecificTimeZone(this DateTimeOffset utcDateTime, int offset)
{
    var offsetTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(offset);
    var localizedDateTime =
        Instant.FromDateTimeOffset(new DateTimeOffset(utcDateTime.DateTime, offsetTimeSpan));
    
    var localizedDateTimeString = localizedDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return localizedDateTimeString;
}
```

I used this logic to get the zone abbreviation for system default, but dont know how to get it for dynamic offsets,

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
var zonedDateTime = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant().InZone(zone);
var zoneName = zonedDateTime.Zone.GetZoneInterval(zonedDateTime.ToInstant()).Name;
```

Any tips or directions would be really helpful.

Comment: Not sure I've understood the question properly but I'm not sure it makes sense to do this as more than 1 timezone can (more likely does) share the same offset at any moment in time. How would you choose between them?

Comment: hmm, is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, get the time zone id from the browser with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` and use that with NodaTime's TZDB provider.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602679/634824